# file.MoveTo doesn't move a file in a shared folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm trying to move a file in a shared folder which I have editor access to a folder in my drive, but I can't.  I can move the file to a different folder in my drive, though.  The code is simple: file.moveTo(toFolder); Am I doing a wrong thing?  How can I move a file in a shared folder to my folder. Here is my code:

```
function sendJudgeReqCN() {
    var fromFolderId = "x";
    var toFolderId = "y";
    var saveFolderId = "z";
    copyAndSaveAllFilesInFolder(fromFolderId, toFolderId, saveFolderId); 
}

function copyAndSaveAllFilesInFolder(fromFolderId, toFolderId, saveFolderId) {
    var fromFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(fromFolderId);
    var toFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(toFolderId);
    var saveFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(saveFolderId);
    var files = fromFolder.getFiles();
    while (files.hasNext()) {
        var file = files.next();
        file.makeCopy(toFolder);
        file.moveTo(saveFolder);
        var fileName = file.getName();
        Logger.log(fileName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Tag Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### It is not enough to be `editor` in order to move a folder out of a shared Drive to your personal drive

- You need to be `organizer` or `owner` to perform this kind of operation
- This behavior is in agreement with the one of the Drive UI, wher only `Manager` but not `Content Manager` can move content from a shared drive to their own drive
- Additional information [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2789107?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I am still a bit confused. I can copy a file in the shared folder to my drive and remove it from the shared folder via Drive UI.  Then, why can't I do it by Google Apps Script?

Comment: There is a difference between "copying and deleting" and "moving out of a shared drive". Test it yourself from the UI!

Comment: Oh, I see.  Thank you very much!  I will.  I also will consider using a shared drive.

Comment: I tried moveTo again today, and surprisingly, it worked.  I could move a file in a shared folder to my drive.  I haven't changed my script so I don't know why it worked this time...

Comment: It's a permisison issue - maybe yoou tried with a different file or your permissions for this file / folder / drive were changed (e.g. by the admin)? Also, it would help to see your code.

Comment: The permissions weren't changed, the owner said...  Here is my code:
function sendJudgeReqCN() {
  var fromFolderId = "x";
  var toFolderId = "y";
  var saveFolderId = "z";
    
  copyAndSaveAllFilesInFolder(fromFolderId, toFolderId, saveFolderId);
}

Comment: function copyAndSaveAllFilesInFolder(fromFolderId, toFolderId, saveFolderId) {
  var fromFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(fromFolderId);
  var toFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(toFolderId);
  var saveFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(saveFolderId);
  
  var files = fromFolder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    file.makeCopy(toFolder);
    file.moveTo(saveFolder);
    var fileName = file.getName();
    Logger.log(fileName);
  }
}

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code rather than pasting it into the comments. Also: what is your permission for the file in question (Editor, organizer, owner?) ?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry.  I put the code in the question.  My permission is "editor".

Comment: I see that `toFolderId` and `saveFolderId` are different. Can you confirm that `fromFolderId` is on a shared drive and `saveFolderId` is on your personal drive? Also, what does the line `Logger.log(file.getAccess(Session.getActiveUser()));` return you?

Comment: Yes.  "fromFolder" is a shared folder and "saveFolder" is in my drive.  Logger.log(file.getAccess(Session.getActiveUser())); returned "OWNER".

Comment: So you are the owner of the file - this is why you can move it - if you were "only" editor or file orgnizer - you could not. See [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/permission) for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much for you information.  It's been quite helpful!